# SQL "select case" gives unexpected output

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the love of god can someone please explain me what is going on here.
I am working on some stored procedure bug fixes, after a lot of struggle, I was able to find out where this strange bug is happening so I've made a simple example for the sake of demonstration.

**Case 1**

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(45) ='0001'
SELECT CASE 0
WHEN -1 THEN ''
WHEN 0 THEN @test
WHEN 1 THEN 12345
END AS 'output'
```

**Case 2**

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(45) ='0001'
SELECT CASE 0
WHEN -1 THEN ''
WHEN 0 THEN @test

END AS 'output'
```

**Case 1:** output is 1

**Case 2:** output is 0001 as expected

What happened to the zeros?
strangely it only removes zeros before the number (no matter what number comes at the end), for example  `DECLARE @test VARCHAR(45) ='1000'` works fine, as far case is concerned  it is clear that case is zero, if I remove `WHEN 0 THEN @test` output is null as expected.

Done some research, found only [this](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6400).
I am using SQL SERVER RC1 2017 as well as SQL SMS.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: WHEN 1 THEN 12345 - 12345 should be '12345' here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference here is that you have mutliple data types in your `THEN`/`ELSE` expressions. In your "CASE 1" you have both `int` and and `varchar` datatypes.

`int` has a higher [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than a `varchar`, so the values are returned as an `int`.

Use the same datatype through out, and this works as you want it to:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(45) ='0001';
SELECT CASE 0 WHEN -1 THEN ''
              WHEN 0 THEN @test
              WHEN 1 THEN '12345' --Note that the value in contained in single quotes
       END AS [output];
```

Comment: thank you for this nice explanation ,is there a way to go around this problem without changing the types because originally i am depending on sql tables

Comment: As Lamak has pointed out, this is a documented feature of SQL server. I strong suggest against having different datatypes being returned in your `THEN`/`ELSE` expressions. If you were using a dataset and one row returned `'A'`, and aonther `1` you would get a conversion error. If the values being returned as an `int` then `CAST` or `CONVERT` the value to a `varchar` inside the `THEN`/`ELSE`. I.e. (using your example) `WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(45), 12345)...`

Comment: just as i was about to write that I've done with cast :D thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

This is because of data type precedence.

The `CASE` expression [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) says about the returned data type:

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression

Meaning it looks **every** set of types in the result expressions. Since you have one where the returned data is an `INT`, then the result of the whole `CASE` expression is `INT` (since it has a higher precedence than `VARCHAR`)

Comment: thank you very much, i can't believe it was  this, but what happens when i put '1000', why that works and can i somehow solve this problem without changing types?

Comment: @Yollo What do you mean?. If you use `'1000'` instead of `12345`, you are using a `VARCHAR` instead of an `INT`....so every result expression is a `VARCHAR` and then the result of the `CASE` expression is a `VARCHAR` too

Comment: i meant if i use '1000' instead of '0001'

Comment: @Yollo but when you use `'1000'` instead of `'0001'`  the result is an `INT`.....an `INT` of value `1000`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the type of the value returned in your last case statement is numeric, so try to change it to

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(45) ='0001'
SELECT CASE 0
WHEN -1 THEN ''
WHEN 0 THEN @test
WHEN 1 THEN '12345'
END AS 'output'
```